# initrd.img contains unnecessary modules after distro upgrade to 22.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel, virtualbox, init

I have several Ubuntu systems running in VirtualBox VMs. They have a long history; started from 16.04 and have been upgraded successively for new LTS releases - but not necessarily all at the same time. I recently upgraded my last 20.04 Ubuntu to 22.04.3, while the other Ubuntu VMs were upgraded to 22.04.1 around Nov'22.

The content of initrd.img of the last Ubuntu VM upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.3 contains more drivers than the initrd.img of the other Ubuntu VMs. Specifically, it additionally contains many graphics drivers/libraries (amdgpu, i915, nvidia, radeon) with their related kernel .ko modules, and crypto .ko-modules of the kernel.

It is not obvious why these are included. The graphics drivers are useless in a VirtualBox environment, and the systems do not utilize any encryption of file systems, partitions, or swap files.

In the Ubuntu VMs that were upgraded in the past, from 20.04 to 22.04.1, these modules are not in initrd.img. In the Ubuntu VM now upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.3, they suddenly appear. I only noticed this, because the /boot-partition is now too small to hold more than 2 kernels, due to the much larger size of the initrd.img files. This now causes problems when installing new kernels.

Of course, I could increase the size of the /boot-partition. But this would be just a medicine for a symptom.

So, the real questions are:

1. Why are those graphics and crypto drivers/modules suddenly included?
2. Is there any procedure to remove those unnecessary drivers/modules from initrd.img?

Just to mention: On these Ubuntu systems I never tampered with the boot-/init-procedures. So, with respect to that, every existing configuration should be "default". Also, the VirtualBox graphics configuration of all these Ubuntu VMs is identical.

Comment: Were all your VMs installed using the same media and not just release!, ie. if they were 16.04, they were all 16.04 & none were 16.04.2, 16.04.5 etc, as the installed defaults are set by media; for example  16.04, 16.04.2 will have different defaults for Desktop installs.  Upgraded systems will keep the default set by users, or if none were set by users then the installation media defaults.

Comment: No, the Ubuntu-VM WITH the problem was installed with 16.04.2 iso-image. One of the other Ubuntu-VMs WITHOUT the problems was installed with 16.04.3 iso-image. However, one Ubuntu-VM that does NOT show the problem was also installed with the 16.04.2 iso-image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why the result differs on your machines, but here's how you can control what goes into the initramfs image:

In `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` there's this block:

```
# 
# MODULES: [ most | netboot | dep | list ]
#
# most - Add most filesystem and all harddrive drivers.
#
# dep - Try and guess which modules to load.
#
# netboot - Add the base modules, network modules, but skip block devices.
#
# list - Only include modules from the 'additional modules' list
#

MODULES=most
```

By switching from `most` to `dep` you'll get a smaller image. But this will only boot on the machine you create it on, so be sure to switch it back before you change any hardware (of the VM).

After changing this, you have to run `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` to apply the configuration. You might want to create a copy of your old initramfs in case there may be required modules missing afterwards.

Comment: All VMs (with or without the problem) have MODULES=most. So, that cannot be the root cause of the problem. Maybe I will try MODULES=dep, but my reasoning for not doing it is that the Ubuntu installer is aware hat it is running in a VM and thus installs MODULES=most for a reason.